# Using Boost's Runge-Kutta integration capability in a templated mathematical model

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost

This is my first time using Boost and templates in general, so I'm mostly looking for a style critique on my C++. In particular, I'd like feedback on:

- `state_type`, is there a good way to do this such that consumers of the library and the private members of the class can use this type? Other than making two separate types
- Location and style of the constants in the code. The intent is to make it entirely compliant to how the original model was written (referenced at the top)
- Templating the container class? It would be nice if we could abstract out `std::vector<U>` to some sort of `typename container C, C<U>` so the users could specify their own containers that implement `operator[]`.
- Style critique on using enums to access specific functions within the model's state
- Other C++11/C++17/C++20 ways to do the same things I do in the code
- A nicer way to do initialization than `static_cast<U>(constant_value)`, that's more correct than `const U = constant_value;`

  ```
  #include <vector> /* representing state */
  #include <algorithm> /* for numeric min/max */
  #include <cmath> /* log, exp, fmod */

  #include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
  #include <ios>
  using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

  typedef double icing_float;

  // [1] - Reference Paper: TBME-01160-2016 
  // [2] - Reference Paper: computer methods and programs in biomedicine 102 (2011) 192–205
  template<typename U = icing_float>
  class ChaseIcing {
      // Each enum maps to an index within the state vector for accessing that
      // function's value.
      enum Function { fn_G = 0
          , fn_Q
          , fn_I
          , fn_P1
          , fn_P2
          , fn_P
          , fn_u_en
      };
      using _state_type = std::vector<U>;

      /* a bunch of constants that should be in the namespace */
      const U n_I = 0.0075; // 1/min, Table II, [1]
      const U d1 = -std::log(0.5)/20.0; // 1/min, Table II, [1]
      const U d2 = -std::log(0.5)/100.0; // 1/min, Table II, [1]
      const U P_max = 6.11; // mmol/min, Table II, [1]

      auto P_min(const _state_type &x)
      {
          return std::min(d2 * x[fn_P2], P_max);
      }

      auto alpha_decay(const U variable, const U decay_parameter)
      {
          return variable / (1.0 + decay_parameter * variable);
      }

      auto Q_frac(const _state_type &x)
      {
          const U a_G = 1.0 / 65.0; // Table II, [1]
          const U Q = x[fn_Q];
          return alpha_decay(Q, a_G);
      }

      // PN(t) -> Parenteral nutrition input, eg IV dextrose
      auto _P(const _state_type &x)
      {
          const U _PN_ext = dextrose_rate; // TODO -> derive this over the network

          return P_min(x) + _PN_ext;
      }

      auto _u_en(const _state_type &x)
      {
          const U k1 = 14.9; // mU * l / mmol/min, Table II, [1]
          const U k2 = -49.9; // mU/min, Table II, [1]
          const U u_min = 16.7; // mU/min, Table II, [1]
          const U u_max = 266.7; // mU/min, Table II, [1]
          const U G = x[fn_G];
          return std::min(std::max(u_min, k1 * G + k2), u_max);
      }

      auto G_dot(const _state_type &x)
      {
          const U p_G = 0.006; // End of section 4.1, in [2]
          const U S_I = 0.5e-3; // TODO: patient specific
          const U G = x[fn_G];
          const U Q = x[fn_Q];
          const U P = _P(x);
          const U EGP = 1.16; // mmol/min Table II, [1]
          const U CNS = 0.3; // mmol/min Table II, [1]
          const U V_G = 13.3; // L, Table II, [1]

          U dGdt = 0.0;
          // G' = -p_G G(t)
          //   - S_I G(t) (Q(t) / (1 + a_G Q(t)))
          //   + (P(t) + EGP -CNS)/V_G
          dGdt += -p_G * G;
          dGdt += -S_I*G * Q_frac(x);
          dGdt += (P + EGP - CNS)/V_G;

          return dGdt;
      }

      auto Q_dot(const _state_type &x)
      {
          const U I = x[fn_I];
          const U Q = x[fn_Q];
          const U n_C = 0.0075; // 1/min, Table II, [1]

          return n_I * (I - Q) - n_C * Q_frac(x);
      }

      auto I_dot(const _state_type &x)
      {
          const U n_K = 0.0542; // 1/min, Table II, [1]
          const U n_L = 0.1578; // 1/min, Table II, [1] 
          const U a_I = 1.7e-3; // 1/mU, Table II, [1]
          const U V_I = 4.0; // L, Table II, [1]
          const U x_L = 0.67; // unitless, Table II, [1]

          const U u_ex = insulin_rate; // TODO: get this over the network

          const U Q = x[fn_Q];
          const U I = x[fn_I];
          const U u_en = _u_en(x);

          auto dIdt = U(0.0);
          // I' = - n_K I(t)
          //  - n_L (I(t)/(1+a_I I(t)))
          //  - n_I (I(t) - Q(t))
          //  + u_ex(t) / V_I
          //  + (1 - x_L) u_en / V_I
          dIdt += -n_K * I;
          dIdt += -n_L * alpha_decay(I, a_I);
          dIdt += -n_I * (I - Q);
          dIdt += u_ex / V_I;
          dIdt += (1.0 - x_L) * u_en / V_I;
          return dIdt;
      }

      auto P1_dot(const _state_type &x)
      {
          const auto D = U(0.0); // enteral feed rate TODO: get from network
          return -d1 * x[fn_P1] + D;
      }

      auto P2_dot(const _state_type &x)
      {
          return -P_min(x) + d1 * x[fn_P1];
      }

      void copy(const ChaseIcing &other)
      {
          data = other.data;
          insulin_rate = other.insulin_rate;
          dextrose_rate = other.dextrose_rate;
      }

      /* data is the container which contains the most up to date representation of the model's state
      *
      * Should only be accessed using the enum Function data type
      */
      _state_type data;
  public:
      using state_type = _state_type;
      void operator() (const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, const U t)
      {
          dxdt[fn_G] = G_dot(x);
          dxdt[fn_Q] = Q_dot(x);
          dxdt[fn_I] = I_dot(x);
          dxdt[fn_P1] = P1_dot(x);
          dxdt[fn_P2] = P2_dot(x);
      }

      auto glucose()
      {
          return data[fn_G];
      }

      auto q()
      {
          return data[fn_Q];
      }

      auto i()
      {
          return data[fn_I];
      }

      auto p1()
      {
          return data[fn_P1];
      }

      auto p2()
      {
          return data[fn_P2];
      }

      int run(U time_start
              , U time_end
              , U dt
              , U insulin_rate_mUpermin
              , U dextrose_rate_mmolpermin)
      {

          insulin_rate = insulin_rate_mUpermin;
          dextrose_rate = dextrose_rate_mmolpermin;

          /* model doesnt modify inplace, so we make copies of its data
          * for integration */
          auto x = data;
          auto step = stepper;

          integrate_const(step, *this, x, time_start, time_end, dt);

          data = x;
          stepper = step;

          return 0;
      }

      /* run the model until time_end using default rates and time step
      */
      int run(U time_end)
      {
          return run(0.0, time_end, 0.1, insulin_rate, dextrose_rate);
      }

      /* run the model with implicitly provided rates
      */
      int run(U time_start, U time_end, U dt)
      {
          return run(time_start, time_end, dt, insulin_rate, dextrose_rate);
      }

      /* insulin_rate is the exogenous IV insulin rate, in mU/min (not mmol/min as listed in [1])
      *
      * Available for public modification, but use run() for most purposes.
      */
      U insulin_rate;

      /* dextrose_rate is the exogenous IV dextrose rate, in mmol/min
      *
      * Available for public modification, but use run() for most purposes.
      */
      U dextrose_rate;

      /* stepper is the Boost integration type, we use RK4 but you may use any you like
      */
      runge_kutta4<state_type> stepper;

      /* public constructor
      */
      ChaseIcing(state_type _data) : data(_data) {};

      /* copy constructor
      */
      ChaseIcing(const ChaseIcing &other)
      {
          copy(other);
      }

      /* assignment operator
      */
      ChaseIcing& operator=(const ChaseIcing &other)
      {
          copy(other);
          return *this;
      }
  };
  ```